# Concatenate alternate rows (one with data, one with some NaN) in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, string-concatenation

I have a dataframe that was obtained from PDF reader on and thus the data reading is a little haywire.

| Column A | Column B | Column C | Column D | Column E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | 5 | 10 | Hello | ABC |
| DEF | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN |
| GHI | 25 | 30 | Bye | Lol |
| JKL | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN |

A sample of the type of dataframe I see. Column A is made of strings. Every alternate row contains a string for column A, but NaN for all other columns.

I want to get the following:

| Column A | Column B | Column C | Column D | Column E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABCDEF | 5 | 10 | Hello | ABC |
| GHIJKL | 25 | 30 | Bye | Lol |

I tried to isolate every 2 rows, and `agg(sum)` the 2 rows, but did not get the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

Using a custom [`groupby.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html) and assuming "Column B" can be used to identify the groups:

```
f = {col: ''.join if is_string_dtype(df[col]) else 'first'
     for col in df}
group = df['Column B'].notna().cumsum()

out = df.groupby(group, as_index=False).agg(f)
```

Alternative, starting groups on rows without missing values:

```
group = df.notna().all(axis=1).cumsum()
```

Or if you really have pairs of rows:

```
import numpy as np

group = np.arange(len(df))//2
```

Output:

```
  Column A  Column B  Column C Column D Column E
0   ABCDEF       5.0      10.0    Hello      ABC
1   GHIJKL      25.0      30.0      Bye      Lol
```